# ubuntu cannot start after bios screen without press shift or f12 button after upgraded to ubuntu 20.04 from 18.04

Tags: grub2, 20.04

I upgraded to ubuntu 20.04 fr0m 18.04. However, it will be stuck in the screen after the bios screen. I noticed that if I press shift key or F12 key during bios screen. It will be able to start the system successfully.

Does anyone know the reason?